# jQuery live modifying css

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any way I can modify some style to all elements that matches a selector, even if they are created after the line of code?

A litle example: If I have a few tabs with li's I could want to do:

```
$("#tabs li").css("color", "black");
$("#tabs li.selected").css("color", "red");
```

And I would like that those lines take effect as `.live` do. If after executing them selected class is added to a li, that li should be applied with the second line (`color: red`).

**Note:** The above code is just an example, I need to do this with some style added by a jquery plugin, so there is no chance of having it on the css file.

Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you do it in css `#tabs li.selected { color: red; }`

Comment: @jimy: I have created a plugin that gives puts three images of background to an element. (It really adds an element to its left an other to its right). I'd like to use that plugin and avoid handling the selection of the element because it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: then u would have to do this in a callback function of that event

Comment: @jimy, you mean it is not posible?

Comment: @diEcho !important should not be used unless you are absolutely stack and there is no other way, because it will cause more problems than solutions, @jimy put ur comment as an answer b4 I do loool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I am fully understanding your question but would something like this not work?
http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/DJ6nZ/

Dynamically adding style tag
http://jsfiddle.net/DJ6nZ/1/

Comment: @Nicky Waites: No. I don't want to have the styling in the css because it actualy is a much more complex styling generated by a plugin.

Comment: @diego mate all you gotta do, instead of `css()` you could do `.attr('style','')` which will clear the css or do regular intervals to check for the styles but could slow down userability,

Comment: @Val: I don't see how using `.attr` instead of `.css` could help me. Also check for the styles in regular intervals is really not a posibility, that is very uggly

Comment: ok lets say on ur css u have `.selector{background:red;}` then ur using ajax aint u to add dynamic data? after success clear its style attr and let the default css file take care of the style

Comment: If you post your plugin it might make it a little easier to figure out what you're trying to do

Comment: I can't see why is my plugin necesary, it has nothing to do with the question I'm asking.

Comment: Maybe dynamically add a style element to the head?  I'm not entirely sure what you mean by this _And I would like that those lines take effect to the current li.selected each time, and not to the li.selected when are executed._

Comment: @Nicky Waites: That may be the way of doing, I'll give it a chance. I'll clarify that in the question.

Comment: @Diego Unless your plugin returns the element that is acted upon I can't think of any other way of doing this.  If that doesn't work I am out of ideas.